# How to design a stack of Raise button and an image in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm new to Flutter, I have a requirement where I need to place a RaisedButton at the edge of an image as shown in the below screenshot(because of privacy, I covered the content on the mockup)
[image]

I tried by changing the padding but it's not working with all the devices in iOS and Android. Please help me out to achieve this for all kind of devices present in iOS and Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class SO extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.orange.shade200,
      body: Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        children: <Widget>[
          Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              Image.asset('assets/images/pngs/cake.png'),
              SizedBox(
                height: 25,
              )
            ],
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            child: Text("sample button"),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

gives
  [image: output]

**EDIT**: One of the non-hacky ways to do this.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final sm = 100.0, lg = 200.0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.red,
      width: lg,
      height: lg,
      alignment: FractionalOffset.bottomCenter +
          FractionalOffset.fromOffsetAndSize(
            Offset(0, sm / 2),
            Size(sm, sm),
          ),
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.blue,
        width: sm,
        height: sm,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Doc Worked for me.

Comment: @user1241241 The code is pretty self-explanatory. Just basic UI logic. Please mention the line you want me to explain and I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @Doc I would like to make the toolbar collapsible and add a scroll view at the bottom. I'm having trouble understanding how the button is anchored perfectly in the middle. Also How I can make the tool bar collapsible :(

Comment: @user1241241 this one is hacky code. actually 1st layer contains image and spacing in a column. the spacing is adjusted to be exactly half the button height. 2nd layer of stack contains the button. Now, alignment is marked as bottomCenter so arrangement starts at bottom center. One of the non-hacky ways is mentioned in edit.

Comment: @Doc thank you!! but it does not work when its stateful widget :( the complete screen is reddish

Comment: @user1241241 That should not happen. Post a question with your code, I'll try to answer it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try Stack in Flutter ?